# How to use reasonml rtop with src files

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop, reason, toplevel, utop

How do I allow rtop to discover my src file directory?

I found an option `-I` and hoped that `rtop -I src` would load my src files in rtop but it still isn't able to find them.

eg.
src/lib.re:

```
let foo = 1;
```

Run command:

`rtop -I src`

```
Reason # open Lib;
Error: Unbound module Lib
```

Comment: Note: question was also asked in https://reasonml.chat/t/how-to-include-src-files-in-rtop/2227

Comment: Thanks, didn't know which one was the official channel to ask questions. I should have linked them together (like you have done) at least though

Answer (score 0):

`open` is a language feature that doesn't know anything about the file system. You'll have to use a special directive instead to load the module from a file.

`utop`/`rtop` mostly uses the same directives as the `ocaml` toplevel, which are documented in the OCaml manual, [here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/toplevel.html#s:toplevel-directives).

If the module has been compiled, you can load the `.cmo` or `.cma` using the `#load` directive:

```
#load "filename";;
```

If that module depends on other modules, you can use `#load_rec` instead to load them recursively.

If your code has not been compiled, and since you `open` it immediately, you can also use the `#use` directive:

```
#use "filename";;
```

Or if you want to load it as if was a top-level module, use `#mod_use` instead.

Comment: Yeah I stumbled on that as well but I couldn't find an easy way to load everything at once like "dune utop". There's a pull request in dune for rtop though, so maybe that's the best way to go. I was just wondering if there was support for something like that without dune or esy. Perhaps I can write a script that creates an init file of some sort that automatically includes all the src modules